# Less number of bytes while reading data from InputStream

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, fileoutputstream

So here is the scenario...I am making bluetooth file transfer in android. First I am sending file name and then once file name is received I send file and receive it too.

Here is the code to receive the file name and file

```
 while (hasFile) {


            try {
                if (Flags.isGotFileName()) {
                    mmInStream.mark(0);
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer,0,8);

                    Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();

                } else {
                    mmInStream.reset();
                    int KB = 0;
                    int compKB = 0;
                    int hasdata = 0;                    
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Flags.getFileName());
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    hasdata=mmInStream.read(buffer,8,1016);
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, hasdata);
                    while ((hasdata = mmInStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        Log.e(TAG, KB + "KB Copied");
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, hasdata);
                        KB++;
                        if (KB - compKB == 200) {
                            Log.e(TAG, KB + "KB Copied");
                            compKB = KB;
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.e("FOSSSS", "CLOSEDDDD");
                    hasFile = false;
                }


            }
        }
```

My problem is that after I get my file name (if part) which is of 8 bytes when I try to receive the file (else part) it is received but its size is 8 bytes less than the original one

I am new to socket communication so I cant figure out how to deal with this.

Comment: 8 bytes less than the original file? And you're reading the first 8 bytes to get the file name? Could it be caused by that first read?

Comment: Yes obviously....but I don't know how to read the full file considering my scenario. Also I am confused about this  while ((hasdata = mmInStream.read(buffer)) != -1) how come -1 comes before 8 bytes.

Comment: It's because you've already read those 8 bytes off of your stream on line 4 of the code you posted.If you want those bytes to be part of your file, you should write them to your FileOutputStream before reading more data, or use a PushBackInputStream

Comment: But those are file name....actual file stats after 8 bytes...see the file size is 794246 bytes and I am getting only 794238 bytes if I exclude the first 8 bytes.

Comment: @ControlAltDel see I edited the code

Comment: Check out- http://stackoverflow.com/a/6160544/3681882

Comment: I checked it out it will return number of bytes read . Here I want to do two simultaneous reads one for 8 bytes and one after that skipping the already read 8 bytes. Can you help me please? @CrakC

Comment: @BhargavMehta Try this `hasdata=mmInStream.read(buffer,0,1016);`

Comment: It didnt work @CrakC...

Comment: I tried copying a textfile...turns out it writes the filename inside the text file...so the inputstream still had that data...So my contents of text file became <filename> then actual contents

Comment: @BhargavMehta If the stream still has the data then why not start from **8** and read it till the end i.e., **1023**?