# InputStream connects to URL but returns nothing

Tags: java, android, url, inputstream

I have an InputStream set to the url of a raw text file hosted online. Each line is a different saying, and the method should be getting the text from the file and saving it to a cache folder for use in the app. There is no issue connecting to the URL, otherwise it would give FileNotFoundException in the logs (tested this), and the cache file is generated but its not saving anything to the cache file (has permissions, tested that too). What is causing this to happen?

Code for reading from the page:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... Params) {
    try {
        File quote = new File("Absolute path to cache");
        URL url = new URL("URL of file");
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(quote);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(buffer);
        os.write(buffer);
        is.close();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Classic misuse of `available()`, and one which is specificaly warned against in the Javadoc.

Comment: 'There is no issue connecting to the URL, otherwise it would give FileNotFoundException'. No. That would give a SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: @greenapps Not correct. It would give a `ConnectException` if the connection failed, a `FileNotFoundException` if the HTP status was 404, both of which are problems with the URL, and a `SocketTimeoutException` if he had set a read timeout and it trigged.

Comment: Ok. For everything is an exception. Not that i can memorize them, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the connection, `is.available()` may or may not be available - function would return zero and result in you writing nothing to the output stream.

Best way to do this is to read until no more data can be read - e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160432/java-inputstream-reading-problem).

Comment: Oh, I see. Now I get the issue. Instead of your implementation though, I just used a fixed 1024 byte buffer. Works perfectly, thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
@Override
   protected void doInBackground(Void... Params) {
      try{
        File quote = new File("Absolute path to cache");
        URL url = new URL("URL of file");
        HttpURLConnection httpCon =
      (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

       if(httpCon.getResponseCode() != 200)
          throw new Exception("Failed to connect");
       }

       InputStream is = httpCon.getInputStream();
       OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(quote);
       byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
       is.read(buffer);
       os.write(buffer);
       is.close();
       os.close();

       }catch(Exception e){
         e.printTrackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }
```

Comment: This wouldn't help - please see my answer above.

Comment: Try it why? What beneficial change does this contain? You hav  to explain. Mere code is not enough. Nothing here cures the underlying problem.