# Input Stream associated with socket is returning data of byte value 0

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, client-server, inputstream

I am using Java sockets (TCP ,read time out set to 30 seconds) to communicate with an external third party server.
The server data is continuous stream comprising of application specific packets.

But from past few days the input stream is returning data which represents byte value 0.

```
 while (connectionIsValid){
 final byte[] buffer= new byte[2];
 in.read( buffer);
  //Print buffer
 //Log line
 Byte[0] is 0 
 Byte[1] is 0

//POST processing if buffer bytes is not equal to OK.
//Other wise bypass post processing
}
```

- There is no exception logged.And as no stream /socket related exception is generated I know java client socket is not closed/time out.

And application is lopping through while loop.

[Updated]

```
    private byte[] readWrapper(InputStream stream, int totalLen ) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer;
        byte[] bufferingBuffer = new byte[0];
        while ( totalLen != 0 ) {
            buffer = new byte[totalLen];
            final int read = stream.read( buffer );
            if(read==-1 || read==0){ 
              //throw exception
             } 
            totalLen = totalLen - read;
            buffer = ArrayUtils.subarray( buffer, 0, read );
            bufferingBuffer = ArrayUtils.addAll( bufferingBuffer, buffer );

        }
        return bufferingBuffer;
    }
```

Comment: You are ignoring the value returned by `read()`. Any conclusions you draw about the contents of the buffer are therefore invalid.

Comment: Yes I should have check/logged the value returned by read().But as I have set read time out of 30 seconds, wouldn't the read() will block for 30 seconds till 2 bytes are read ? That's the thought process in assuming 2 bytes are actually read.

Comment: No, it will block until (a) at least one byte is transferred, (b) end of stream occurs, or (c) an exception is thrown. This is all clearly stated in the Javadoc. There is nothing there that says it will attempt to fill the buffer.

Comment: Ok.But case (a) is applicable in my scenario.As application after establishing the socket, does precondition check by reading 10 initial bytes and then enters the while loop.so more than one byte is transferred through the socket.

Comment: That is simply untrue. It could be case (a), which is *at least one byte*, not 'more than one byte', or case (b), which implies zero bytes. With this code it is impossible for you to know which, or how many. Fix the code.

Comment: Yes,I need to include the check for case (b) -  when read returns -1, close the connection and establish fresh connection.Just to confirm - If read has returned -1, then any further invocation on read () will always return -1 so there is no use of doing a read() again even after some delay.

Comment: Yes, and you also need to include a check for only receiving one byte, instead of assuming both array elements are set. The fundamental problem with this question remains. Yoiu don't have any evidence here that shows both bytes were zero.

Comment: Yes,I have put that check as well i.e read will be performed in loop till I have read desired no. of bytes and if any read will return 0 or -1,break the loop and close the socket connection.I am adding the check for 0 also  to avoid infinite loop just in case, as read is now done in loop.

Comment: ****Not in the code you posted.*** The code you posted cannot distinguish between 0, 1, or 2 bytes being received. If you have other code that exhibits the same problem you should post it here, in your question. Otherwise there is no question to answer.

Comment: If you're expecting anybody to read that illegible mess you're mistaken. You were asked to post it *in your question.*

Comment: @EJP - Apologies , I meant to delete the comment yesterday but missed it some how.I have updated the post with method structure which can be used to read data.So far I have not encountered the scenario where read is returning 0.So I am not sure if that check for 0 is necessary or not.Intention is to avoid getting stuck in loop hence he check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all that. The JDK already contains a method for it:

```
private byte[] readChunkedData(InputStream stream, int size) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(stream);
    din.readFully(buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

This version (a) works (b) doesn't require third-party classes and (c) throws `EOFException` if there aren't `size` bytes left in the stream.

Comment: I have seen this method but if I want to log the return value  of each read() if the value is <=0.As I am working with remote stream and I was wondering if read() returns 0 (if it's -1, stream has ended for sure) and let's assume I continue reading for another 100 iterations will I still get the data ! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160432/java-inputstream-reading-problem)

Comment: Read this post and Alvin's comment implies even if read() returns 0 there might be possibility of getting data in further iterations.[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160432/java-inputstream-reading-problem

Comment: @Alvin is completely mistaken about that. The Javdoc for `InputStream.read()` clearly states that it blocks until at least one byte is transferred or end of stream or an exception occurs. The only way it can return zero is if you supply a zero length buffer or count, which would be a programming error. I've given you working code. What happens when you tried it?

Comment: - In that case, I will use DataInputStream as Input stream wrapper as suggested.Thank you for continuing with the discussions.

Comment: @blueSky Thanks for your thanks, but yet again it baffles me why people ask questions here when they're not going to try the answers they are given.